# Infinite loop when deploying a war on tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, war, webarchive

I try to deploy a war into Tomcat 7.0.29. I'm having the following log stack :

```
GRAVE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of context descriptors to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:574)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1413)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2227)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2227)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2227)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2227)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2227)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2227)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2227)
```

(Many stack frames ommited...)

Does anybody face the same problem ?

Comment: can you post the web.xml contents?

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53871

Answer (score 4):

This is reported upstream as issue [#53871](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53871) in Tomcat. The problem appears to be with annotation scanning, and Tomcat 7.0.38 includes a clearer error message.

From the bug report:

> Due to dependency management problems I deployed a WAR file containing two JAR files containing different versions of a library, where version 1 contained a class A which inherited from B and another version 2 which contained a class B inheriting from A.
>   The classes were loaded in such an order that A and B cyclically inherited from each other which leads to a stack overflow in populateSCIsForCacheEntry because it does not detect cycles in the inheritance tree.

This was exactly the problem in my case: an old version of `dom4j` bundled an incompatible version of `jaxen`. The new error diagnostic in 7.0.38 showed exactly which classes formed a loop and I fixed it by upgrading those dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also encountering this issue in Tomcat 7.0.**29** and Tomcat 7.0.**30**. However with Tomcat 7.0.**28** everything works fine, so I suspect it's Tomcat issue, that was recently introduced.

The error encountered in 7.0.**29** and 7.0.**30**, when starting Tomcat and deploying a war file:

```
14:01:06,380 ERROR [HostConfig:576] Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of context descriptors to complete java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:574)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1413)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2243)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2260)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2260)
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround : I changed the name of the **WAR** (no finalName in pom.xml and changed the artifact version) and it worked .... why? I don't know till now!

A real and a genuine solution? Definitely a new **Tomcat** Release . . .

Answer (score 1):

For me this behavior reproduced in IntelliJ Idea when I set the Application Context to the same name as the the Maven atrifactId in the .pom file.
E.g. my artifactId is 'test', then I set the Application Context (Edit configuration -> Tomcat Server -> Deployment, select the exploded artifact) to '/test'. As soon as I changed the Application Context, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lower version of **Tomcat**. There are problems with the version of **Tomcat** you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I think it was caused by **Tomcat 7**, so when I changed to **Tomcat 6.0.35**, the problem resolved itself like a charm.