# Tomcat7: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

Tomcat **7.0.30** fails on startup (does not manage to start) with this exception:

```
SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
```

The following is the exception's full stack trace:

```
==> /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out <==

Sep 17, 2012 2:43:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/cfwd.war
Sep 17, 2012 2:43:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWARs
SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1302)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:248)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1454)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:296)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Note that `cfwd.war` is the only war file in the `webapps` directory (in addition to the usual default contents, as `examples`, `manager`, etc etc).

Any ideas about possible causes for this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263684/infinite-loop-when-deploying-a-war-on-tomcat-7

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by an issue with the applciation class hierarchy. One example I have seen is with out of date classes introducing circular inheritance.

If you upgrade to 7.0.47 you'll get a more informative error message as to what the problem is. Alternatively, a clean build of your applciation may be enough to clean things up.